# Final Mix Runoff Workflow

Tags: mix, stage, dubbing-stage

I'm currently specing a new mix room to be built and wanted to get input if you're willing to share it on runoffs and how your line works:

How many Pro Tools stations do you have on your dub stage? or If you've worked on a major dub-stage, what would be the ideal amount of Pro Tools systems?

Are you set up to run all stems at once? Is this ideal to have?

What is your workflow for running off your mixes?

What do you wish you had set up that you don't for running off?

Comment: That's a sexy little 10K next to your name... Well done on getting so many rep points!

Answer (score 2):

There are usually 3 PT stations on a dub stage. One for the fx editor, one for the dialog editor, and one for the music editor. The mixers often also have monitors/mouse set up on some sort of kvm switch so they can look, take control of any of the three systems while they are mixing. The stems are then usually routed to a recorder and/or additional PT rig in the machine room and recorded all at once.

This system is efficient and works well when every station has a talented person behind it  :)

Comment: Lol. Nice caveat @Justin :D